# Show image and long description on change of dropdownlist using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

How to show images and long text on change of a dropdownlist. Say I have list of work their image and long description of around 500 words. when I select work its name shows in right side div as heading and below that work image and its long description.

Comment: Can you show us your code? or a plunker?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.